# A better way of getting draft posts that has a particular post meta using get_posts function

Tags: plugin-development, post-meta, get-posts

I'm developing a simple WordPress plugin as part of my WordPress learning. It's about bulk post approval. The full plugin code is given in this question: [Bulk post approval and publishing doesn't work](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/413439/229637).

The plugin works the way I want it to, but I'm now trying to improve it.

For example, the following function is part of the plugin code:

```php
function karma_get_pre_publish_posts() {
    // get all draft posts with 'approve' custom field set to 'pre-publish'
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'draft'
    );
    $approval_posts = array();
    $draft_posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $draft_posts as $post ) {
        if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'approve', true ) == 'pre-publish' ) {
            $approval_posts[] = $post;
        }
    }
    return $approval_posts;
}
```

It gets all the draft posts using `get_posts` function, and then checks for all the posts that has post meta `approve` set to `'pre-publish'` using `get_post_meta` function.

The function works, but I was thinking: if I have many such posts, say 100, then the code will basically run `get_post_meta` function 100 times. I'm assuming WordPress runs SQL queries in the background every time I use `get_post_meta` function. This doesn't look very efficient.

I can probably run a single SQL join query [like this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/10417/229637) to get all the necessary post data, but I'm wondering if there is a more standard way of doing the same in WordPress.

Any suggestions? Any related documentation link would be helpful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the post meta arguments that `get_posts` function already supports. So, there is no need to use `get_post_meta` function in a PHP loop.

For your use case, post meta related arguments can be used in one of the two possible ways:

1. Either using `meta_key`, `meta_value`, `meta_compare` arguments;
2. Or, using the `meta_query` argument which supports an array of different post meta checks and hence is more powerful.

Using any of these methods returns all the necessary post data in one go.

### Method-1:

The following example uses `meta_key`, `meta_value`, `meta_compare` arguments to achieve what you want:

```php
function karma_get_pre_publish_posts() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'    => 'post',
        'post_status'  => 'draft',
        'meta_key'     => 'approve',
        'meta_value'   => 'pre-publish',
        'meta_compare' => '='
    );

    return get_posts( $args );
}
```

### Method-2:

The `meta_query` argument on the other hand requires an array of one or more argument arrays to query the posts with related post meta.

Like this:

```php
function karma_get_pre_publish_posts() {
    // Yes, $meta_query argument has to be coded as an array of arrays.
    $meta_query = array(
        array(
            'key' => 'approve',
            'value' => 'pre-publish',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    );
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'meta_query' => $meta_query
    );

    return get_posts( $args );
}
```

### Further reading:

- Post meta related arguments (or parameters) of the `get_posts` function come from the `parse_query` method of `WP_Query` class. You may check the [`parse_query` method documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/) for more details.
- Also, since the internal implementation related to post meta arguments is using the `WP_Meta_Query` class, you will also find some details in [`WP_Meta_Query` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/#accepted-arguments) and [`WP_Meta_query` constructor](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/__construct/) documentations.

There are user contributed examples in these documentations with more advanced use cases, including multiple post meta comparisons in a single query.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot.